# Java and HttpsUrlConnection ignoring ssl certificates

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

1)I am trying to consume https url by ignoring ssl certificates

2)I have tried to hit **https url request to Google Geolocation api** url but I am getting below response indicating I am making wrong program.

Because I tried the url via Postman and it shows correct output.

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT, Date: Sun, 26 Nov 2017 07:38:48 GMT, Vary: Origin, Vary: X-Origin, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: GSE, Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35", Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity@5c18298f}
```

I have also used other sources but could not find out the hint for the same.

**Here is my Code**

```
public void givenIgnoringCertificates_whenHttpsUrlIsConsumed_thenCorrect()
    throws Exception {
String HOST_WITH_SSL="https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=XXX";
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true).build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLContext(sslContext)
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(HOST_WITH_SSL);
httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
System.out.println(response);
}
```

> Can anyone guide how to hit https url correctly?

Comment: If you don't want it secure why are you using HTTPS?

Comment: @EJP you are correct.I am a beginner so I thought to communicate to https server you can only use https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in the code requires a POST request and you are sending a GET.

With a GET request it returns 404 even in Postman.

Changing the code to use HttpPost solves your problem.

Google has a valid certificate, you probably should not try ignore certificates though.

Comment: I did the changes and got the answer. Thankx

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by helospark,I changed the get Url to post.

```
public void givenIgnoringCertificates_whenHttpsUrlIsConsumed_thenCorrect()
        throws Exception {
    String HOST_WITH_SSL = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyD-5wmiRDIWRCmUCiI5utqzoro8cbNyyi8";
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true).build();

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
            .build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HOST_WITH_SSL);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String body = handler.handleResponse(response);
    System.out.println(response);
    System.out.println(body);
}
```